# Floating Point Arithmetic dealing with a Taylor expansion for e^-x

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

Suppose we want to compute $e^{-a}$ for $a>>1$. Which of the following techniques should I use?

(a) Taylor expansion for $e^{-x}$ about $x=0$ or
(b) Taylor expansion for $e^x$ about $x=0$, then take its reciprocal.

Would a Taylor expansion about $e^{-x}$ give cancellation? Is that what this question is getting at?

Comment: Are you forced to do it one of these two ways?

Comment: In case (a) for increasingly large values of $a\gt\gt1$ we would see that the Taylor series expansion will diverge to $\pm\infty$ depending on the number of terms used to estimate $e^{-a}$. In case (b) for increasingly large values of $a\gt\gt1$ the reciprocal of the Taylor series expansion always tends to a value of zero when at least two terms of the expansion are used. As the actual value of $e^{-a}$ should tend to zero for $a\gt\gt1$ I would suggest the use of (b).

Comment: What about case (c), compute $n=\lfloor x/\ln2\rfloor$ and then have $e^{-x}=2^{-n}e^{n\ln2-x}$ with any sensible approximation for the now reduced exponent?

Comment: The radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $\,e^x\,$ at $\,x=0\,$ is infinity. Thus, you **could** use it for case (a) but you need to use more precision since the alternating sum causes [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).

Comment: @LutzLehmann That's the smart way to do it, but we don't know if it is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, the direct, naive evaluation of a sum $a_1+...+a_n$ will have accumulated floating point errors of a size $(|a_1|+...+|a_n|)\mu$ where $\mu$ is the floating point machine constant. In your case this means that the series evaluation of $e^x$ has a floating point error, additional to the truncation error, of $e^{|x|}\mu$.

- This means that variant (a) computes $e^{-x}$, $x>0$, as $e^{-x}+e^{x}\delta$ with $|δ|\le μ$. For medium sized $x$ the error will surpass the value, making the result meaningless.
- In variant (b) the result is computed as $e^{-x}/(1+δ)$, which is acceptable for a floating point operation.
- Most actual algorithms implement variant (c), or a further refinement, where in $e^{-x}=2^n(1+m)$ the exponent $n$ is first computed as integer part of $x/\ln2$ and then an optimized interpolation polynomial over the interval $[0,1]$ is used for the exponential of the remainder  $x-n\ln2$.
- Another possibility is (d) to use the floating point form of $x=2^n(1+m)$ to compute $e^{-x}=(e^{-(1+m)/2})^{2^{n+1}}$ for $n>0$ via repeated squaring of the inner exponential.

Comment: Why do we compute the truncation error as $e^{|x|}\mu$ with the absolute value? I expected the truncation error to be $e^{-x}(1+ \delta)$.

Comment: The first is the result of the raw, naive series evaluation. The second is the target for actual implementations, which is achieved using properties of the exponential function, reducing any exponential series approximation to small arguments.

Comment: sorry let me clarify. AFAIK, the general rule of thumb is that $fl(x) = x(1+ \delta)$ for $|\delta| \leq \mu$. So I am confused why the truncation error is $e^{|x|}\mu$. Was wondering if you would be able to help explain that part?

Comment: In the evaluation of $e^x=\sum \frac{x^k}{k!}$, the evaluation of the powers gives a cumulative error contribution of about $\sum\frac{|x|^k}{k!}k\mu=e^{|x|}|x|\mu$. Then the summation of the terms gives another contribution of $\left(\sum\frac{|x|^k}{k!}\right)\mu=e^{|x|}\mu$ per the summation error rule explained on top. // This just means that the power series alone is not able to give an accurate result for large arguments $x$.